# Count Date intervals by group in R taking into account that when date overlap just count them once

Tags: r, data.table

There is a date column for different ID group and each observations has a *number of days* to be added number.

```
library("data.table")

data <- data.table(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   Date =c("01/Sep/2020","11/Sep/2020", "01/Sep/2020",
                           "08/Sep/2020", "01/Aug/2020", "04/Aug/2020",
                           "10/Aug/2020"),
                   days_to_be_added = c(10,10,10,08,05,05,30))

data[, Date := as.Date(Date, format = "%d/%h/%Y")]
```

```
   ID       Date      days_to_be_added
1:  1 2020-09-01               10
2:  1 2020-09-11               10
3:  2 2020-09-01               10
4:  2 2020-09-08                8
5:  3 2020-08-01                5
6:  3 2020-08-04                5
7:  3 2020-08-10               30
```

I have to get the date interval for each **ID** group such that each date is added to the 'days_to_be_added_group' and number of days is counted between them. If any date overlaps then they are counted only once.

Example :
For **ID 2** :

```
3rd row : **1 Sep 2020** to **10 Sep 2020** is 10 days [as Days_to_be_added is 10]
4th row : **8 Sep 2020** to **15 Sep 2020** is 8 days [as Days to be added is 8]
But the total number of days for ID 2 should come as **15 days** since 8 Sep to 10 Sep is overlap for the ID group and should be counted once.
```

````
**Expected output:**

ID  Number_of_days
1    20
2    15
3    38
```

**Note** If there are any **Date** as "NA" they should be ignored
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one approach.

Add rows for each day using `seq.Date` starting with `Date` for each `ID`, and continuing for `days_to_be_added`.

Then, the `Number_of_days` would be the total number of unique `day` values for each `ID`, so that overlapping `day` would not be double counted.

```
data[, .(day = seq.Date(Date, by = 'day', length.out = days_to_be_added))
     , by = .(ID, 1:nrow(data))
     ][, .(Number_of_days = uniqueN(day)), by = ID][]
```

**Output**

```
   ID Number_of_days
1:  1             20
2:  2             15
3:  3             38
```